# Join/Merge two dataframes with duplicate indices, without all permutations returned as row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

These are the two dataframes I am trying to merge together.

df1

```
    Year    Month   Debit
0   2020    December    6500.0
1   2020    December    1566.0
2   2020    December    200.0
3   2020    December    100.0
4   2020    December    40.0
5   2021    January     8000.0
6   2021    January     2000.0
7   2021    January     2000.0
8   2021    January     1975.0
9   2021    January     1635.0
```

df2

```
    Year    Month   Credit
0   2020    December    1560.0
1   2020    December    198.0
2   2020    December    130.0
3   2021    January     10000.0
4   2021    January     8000.0
5   2021    January     5000.0
6   2021    January     5000.0
7   2021    January     4000.0
8   2021    February    2000.0
9   2021    February    150.0
```

When I merge them together, the result I expect is for the rows of `Debit` and `Credit` columns to return a value for those specific `Year` and `Month` if present, otherwise returning `NaN`.

**Expected Result-**

```
    Year    Month   Debit   Credit
0   2020    December    6500.0  1560.0
1   2020    December    1566.0  198.0
2   2020    December    200.0   130.0
3   2020    December    100.0   NaN
4   2020    December    40.0    NaN
5   2021    January     8000.0  10000.0
6   2021    January     2000.0  8000.0
7   2021    January     2000.0  5000.0
8   2021    January     1975.0  5000.0
9   2021    January     1635.0  4000.0
10  2021    February    NaN     2000.0
11  2021    February    NaN     150.0
```

But the result I get is all the permutations of the values of `Debit` and `Credit`.

**Observed Result-**

```
    Year    Month   Debit   Credit
0   2020    December    6500.0  1560.0
1   2020    December    6500.0  198.0
2   2020    December    6500.0  130.0
3   2020    December    1566.0  1560.0
4   2020    December    1566.0  198.0
5   2020    December    1566.0  130.0
6   2020    December    200.0   1560.0
7   2020    December    200.0   198.0
8   2020    December    200.0   130.0
9   2020    December    100.0   1560.0
10  2020    December    100.0   198.0
11  2020    December    100.0   130.0
12  2020    December    40.0    1560.0
13  2020    December    40.0    198.0
14  2020    December    40.0    130.0
15  2021    January     8000.0  10000.0
16  2021    January     8000.0  8000.0
17  2021    January     8000.0  5000.0
18  2021    January     8000.0  5000.0
19  2021    January     8000.0  4000.0
20  2021    January     2000.0  10000.0
21  2021    January     2000.0  8000.0
22  2021    January     2000.0  5000.0
23  2021    January     2000.0  5000.0
24  2021    January     2000.0  4000.0
25  2021    January     2000.0  10000.0
26  2021    January     2000.0  8000.0
27  2021    January     2000.0  5000.0
28  2021    January     2000.0  5000.0
29  2021    January     2000.0  4000.0
30  2021    January     1975.0  10000.0
31  2021    January     1975.0  8000.0
32  2021    January     1975.0  5000.0
33  2021    January     1975.0  5000.0
34  2021    January     1975.0  4000.0
35  2021    January     1635.0  10000.0
36  2021    January     1635.0  8000.0
37  2021    January     1635.0  5000.0
38  2021    January     1635.0  5000.0
39  2021    January     1635.0  4000.0
```

Here is the code to reproduce the example-

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Year': {0: 2020,
  1: 2020,
  2: 2020,
  3: 2020,
  4: 2020,
  5: 2021,
  6: 2021,
  7: 2021,
  8: 2021,
  9: 2021},
 'Month': {0: 'December',
  1: 'December',
  2: 'December',
  3: 'December',
  4: 'December',
  5: 'January',
  6: 'January',
  7: 'January',
  8: 'January',
  9: 'January'},
 'Debit': {0: 6500.0,
  1: 1566.0,
  2: 200.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 40.0,
  5: 8000.0,
  6: 2000.0,
  7: 2000.0,
  8: 1975.0,
  9: 1635.0}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Year': {0: 2020,
  1: 2020,
  2: 2020,
  3: 2021,
  4: 2021,
  5: 2021,
  6: 2021,
  7: 2021,
  8: 2021,
  9: 2021},
 'Month': {0: 'December',
  1: 'December',
  2: 'December',
  3: 'January',
  4: 'January',
  5: 'January',
  6: 'January',
  7: 'January',
  8: 'February',
  9: 'February'},
 'Credit': {0: 1560.0,
  1: 198.0,
  2: 130.0,
  3: 10000.0,
  4: 8000.0,
  5: 5000.0,
  6: 5000.0,
  7: 4000.0,
  8: 2000.0,
  9: 150.0}})

new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Year','Month'])
new_df
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible by pd.merge IMHO. You need custom function.